# Need Help on Java Programmin HandlingException

Tags: java, netbeans

so i just got this Homework

> Make a Java Program using GUI(JpanelForm) with implementation of
>   handling Exception ArithmeticException, NegativeArraySizeException,
>   ArrayIndexOutofBOundsException, and NullPointerException

```
/**
 *
 * @author Inoyama
 */
public class OLCHandlingException extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form OLCHandlingException
     */
    public OLCHandlingException() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField2.setText(" ");
        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Bilangan 1");

        jLabel2.setText("Bilangan 2");

        jLabel3.setText("Hasil");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 106, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(208, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(65, 65, 65)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 56, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addContainerGap(117, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

// TODO add your handling code here:
      String A_String;

      A_String=jTextField1.getText();
      int A = Integer.parseInt(A_String);
      jTextField1.setText(""+A);
    }                                           

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         String B_String;
         String C_String;
         C_String = jTextField1.getText();
         int C = Integer.parseInt(C_String);

         B_String=jTextField2.getText();
         int B = Integer.parseInt(B_String);

         try{
             float total;
             total = C * B;
             jTextField3.setText("Result is "+total);
         }
         catch(NegativeArraySizeException e){
              System.out.println("Failed");
         }
    }                                           

    private void jTextField3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OLCHandlingException.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OLCHandlingException.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OLCHandlingException.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OLCHandlingException.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new OLCHandlingException().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

if possible can you give me explanation + example of program usage and why my program not working
it doexnt calculat C * B ...

Comment: Please put your code in proper indentation.

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.io/

Comment: be more specific, its enough if you put the buisness logic.

Comment: so u are not getting any output not even an exception when you press enter

Comment: that was nice explanation about java is not javascript @DipenShah

Comment: @psyco how do i put code in proper way?i just copy pasted from my script... and thing like that happened

Comment: @Priyamal http://s31.postimg.org/uyli1anwb/Java.png this is what happened when i tried to run it

Answer (score 0):

```
public void exceptionExamples(){       

         String B_String = null;
         String C_String = null;
         C_String = jTextField1.getText();
         B_String=jTextField2.getText();
         try{
         int C = Integer.parseInt(C_String);
         int B = Integer.parseInt(B_String);
         float total;
         total = C * B;
         jTextField3.setText("Result is "+total);
         }
         catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
              System.out.println("Failed");
         }

}
```

you are not handling the `exceptions` correctly you dont need to handle a `negativearrayexception` when trying to `convert a string to a number` the `exception` type you need to handle is `NumberFormatException` , bt ifyou are accepting `Exception class object` in your `catch` it will handle every `exception`
which i have done . 
by the way you are getting a `numberformat exception` because you are having a `" 4"` this is wrong it has a `space` before the `4` change this to `"4"` and try the code.